# MPI non-blocking send and receive ordering

Tags: mpi, nonblocking, openmpi

On a 2-core system, for the following code

```
if(rank == 0)
  {
    MPI_Isend(A) // to rank 1
    // Do something else.
    MPI_Isend(B) // to rank 1
    // Do something else.
    MPI_Wait(B is sent)
    MPI_Wait(A is sent)
  }
  else
  {
    MPI_Irecv(buffer1) // Listen to rank 0
    // Do something else.
    MPI_Irecv(buffer2) // Listen to rank 0
    // Do something else.
    MPI_Wait(buffer2 is finished receiving)
    MPI_Wait(buffer1 is finished receiving)
  }
```

Would rank 1 be guaranteed to receive A in buffer 1, and B in buffer 2?

Thank you!

Comment: your example is minimal but i would say yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPI messages are "non-overtaking". Two messages from the same source can  not arrive in a different order from how they are sent (blocking case) or initiated (non-blocking case). Of course, you can always set your mind at ease by specifying different tags.